# How to monitor a facebook wall via code

Tags: c#, iphone, facebook

I have a friend that uses facebook very rarely. What I would like to do is getting a notification whenever he publishes something on his own Wall.

Facebook doesn't automatically notify you unless you are messaged or when someone posts on your wall.

I'd like to write an application that would monitor his wall for changes then notify me when there is something new.  I'd like the notification to go to my iPhone.

I thought that maybe I could create a custom notification using the Facebook API or the feed filter manager; but I'm not sure if that's possible because I don't want to apply a filter to my main Facebook account page.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could approach this?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a question in here.  You might want to rewrite this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Facebook has a feature now where you can put people into groups like "Close Friends", "Family" etc. and you can enable notifications on those groups for posting activity and so on.

Comment: @Chris: I'm asking suggestions on the implementation of an applications with the features I described.
->C.Mcackney
Yes I though about creating a one person list, but didn't know you can get all the activity from that list as notifications, how do I enable thes options for the list ?

Comment: @C.McAtackney: I've not found any special option to get notifications about their activity. Updates Customization already go in the news feed, but Notification != Update in the feed, notification is somewhat more personal and direct. It would eliminate the need to manually check.

Comment: @C.McAtackney Ok Family doesn't have the option, but "Close Friends" yes it does.

Comment: @Relok: I just modified this to turn it into a question based on your comments.  That should help keep it from being closed as "not a real question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to create a list with only him inside, you would have it displayed on your Facebook homepage with a count increasing each time he posts something ?
It wouldn't *destroy* your homepage, as it's very easy to switch from your usual News Feed to a customized list.

Because you could do what you say, but your friend would have to be a user of your app and give some special permissions to read his wall even when he's not on the app' (offline_access etc...).

You **can** do it, but is it necessary for what you want ?

Comment: Yes the idea is nice but iPhone App(native) doesn't have list like that.

Also it involves to check manually on Facebook not getting a notification on my iPhone, so manual check is needed.

Comment: I'm not sure this needs code - you could just add them to your 'Close Friends' list on Facebook and enable email notifications for that list

Comment: @Igy I've found the option, only "Close Friends" have the option, does this includes standard notifications or just Email notifications, cause I don't use Email notifications on my iPhone, due to many accounts and mails a day, I receive.